# DatePicker only allow today, tomorrow and next day

Tags: jquery, datepicker

How can I change the following code to restrict the date picker to allow only today, tomorrow, next day to be selectable?

```
$(function() {
    $(".datepicker").datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
        minDate: 0
    });

    /*
    $('body').on('focus', ".datepicker", function(){
        $(this).datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy' });
    })
    */

    $('.cal').on('click', function(e) {
        var target = $(this).closest('.calendar').find('.datepicker');
        target.datepicker('show');
    });
});

</script>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the `maxDate` property. If you provide it an integer, it will be taken as the number of days from today, so `2` would work in your case:

```
$(".datepicker").datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
    minDate: 0,
    maxDate: 2
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/5ooh4mk7/)